Shared With Us in SharePoint online not showing Documents
I have created SharePoint Team Sites (Site A) and (Site B) and using Share button to share files and folders with Microsoft 365 Groups. However, members of (Site A or Site B)  are not able to see anything under "Shared with us" in their site? any ideas what is missing?
Thanks
Wajih

When a file/folder is first shared with you, you will receive an email notification that contains a link to the item. Afterwards, you may find this item on the SharePoint website without using the email. "Shared with Us" is available for users with Microsoft Accounts. Non-Microsoft Account users can access resources with a temporary passcode.
